# bash sort quoted csv files by numeric key

Tags: bash, sorting, csv

I have the following input csv file:

```
"aaa","1","xxx"
"ccc, Inc.","6100","yyy"
"bbb","609","zzz"
```

I wish to sort by the second column as numbers,
I tried

```
sort --field-separator=',' --key=2n
```

the problem is that since all values are quoted, they don't get sorted correctly by -n (numeric) option. is there a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little trick, which uses a double quote as the separator:

```
sort --field-separator='"' --key=4 -n
```

Comment: For other readers: note the key=4, not key=2   ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Dropping your example into a file called sort2.txt I found the following to work well.
`sort -t'"' -k4n sort2.txt`
Using sort with the following commands (thank you for the refinements Jonathan)

-t[optional single character separator other than tab. Defined within the single quotes]'"'.

-k4 choose the value in the fourth key.(k)delimited by ", and on the 4th key value

-n numeric sort

file name avoid the use of chaining as unnecessary

Hope this helps!

Comment: `less` behaves like `cat` when its output goes to a pipe, and `sort` is perfectly capable of reading the file (so `sort -t '"' -k 4n sort2.txt` would be better; it would sort numerically, too).

Comment: Also, a first field containing `"Joe ""The Man"" Bloggs"` (valid CSV) would throw your field count off horribly.  You can level that complaint at my answer, too, but it would require something like `"Joe ""The Man"",""The Guy"" Bloggs"` to confuse it, which is even more esoteric (and one of my 'reasonable assumptions' is that such a string would not appear — there'd be a space after the embedded comma).

Comment: Updated based on your suggestions, Jonathan. Thank you, I forgot that sort can pull the file directly.

Answer (score 2):

For a quoted `csv` use a language that has a proper `csv` parser. Here is an example using `perl`.

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -lne '
    chomp; 
    push @line, [ parse_line(",", 0, $_) ];
}{ 
    @line = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @line;
    for (@line) {
        local $" = qw(",");
        print qq("@$_");
    }
' file
```

**Output:**

```
"aaa","1","xxx"
"bbb","609","zzz"
"ccc, Inc.","6100","yyy"
```

**Explanation:**

- Remove the new line from input using `chomp` function.
- Using a code module [Text::Parsewords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) parse the quoted line and store it in an array of array without the quotes.
- In the `END` block, sort the array of array on second column and assign it to the original array of array.
- For every item in our array of array, we set the output list separator to `","` and we print it with preceding and trailing `"` to create the lines in original format.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't going to be a really simple solution.  If you make some reasonable assumptions, then you could consider:

```
sed 's/","/^A/g' input.csv |
sort -t'^A' -k 2n |
sed 's/^A/","/g'
```

This replaces the `","` sequence with <kbd>Control-A</kbd> (shown as `^A` in the code), then uses that as the field delimiter in `sort` (the numeric sort on column 2), and then replace the <kbd>Control-A</kbd> characters with `","` again.

If you use `bash`, you can use the [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism `$'\1'` to embed the control characters visibly into the script; you just have to finish the single-quoted string before the escape, and restart it afterwards:

```
sed 's/","/'$'\1''/g' input.csv |
sort -t$'\1' -k 2n |
sed 's/'$'\1''/","/g'
```

Or play with double quotes instead of single quotes, but that gets messy because of the double quotes that you are replacing.  But you can simply type the characters verbatim and editors like `vim` will be happy to show them to you.

Comment: Awesome. In the bash command, is the sort supposed to still use `^A`, or should it use `$'\1'` as well?

Comment: The Bash [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) operator `$'\1'` uses printable characters only (backslash and digit 1) whereas the `^A` in the first command sequence has to be typed as control-A.  They map to the same character.  You can use either; you could use `^A` in one and `$'\1'` in the other, but that would probably confuse people unnecessarily.  (And yes, my code was self-inconsistent; apologies, and thanks again, Dale Anderson!)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the values in the CSV file are optionally quoted, only when necessary. In this case, using `"` as a separator is not reliable.

Example:

```
"Forest fruits",198
Apples,456
bananas,67
```

Using `awk`, `sort` and `cut`, you can sort the original file, here by the first column :

```
awk -F',' '{
    a = $1; # or the column index you want
    gsub(/(^"|"$)/, "", a);
    print a","$0
}' file.csv | sort -k1 | cut -d',' -f1 --complement
```

This will bring the column you want to sort on in front without quotes, then sort it the way you want, and remove this column at the end.